# How to multiply two quaternions

Tags: php, c++, function, 3d, quaternions

I have two quaternions, as an example:

```
    w     x     y     z
1:  0.98  0.08  0.17  -0.01
2:  0.70  0.70  0.0   0.0
```

I need to multiply them, to get a third one, with all rotations in it.

How do I do that in PHP/C++/PAWN?

Comment: [Are questions seeking answers in either of two or more languages on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408896/are-questions-seeking-answers-in-either-of-two-or-more-languages-on-topic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should choose a language. In C++, the Boost.Math library includes [quaternions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/quaternions.html); I don't know about the other languages you mention. Or for simple multiplication, you could just use the multiplication table (which I copied from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)):

```
*| 1  i  j  k
-------------
1| 1  i  j  k
i| i -1  k -j
j| j -k -1  i
k| k  j -i -1
```

For example, `i*j` gives the value in row `i` and column `j`, which is `k`.

So, assuming your quaternions represent `w*1 + x*i + y*j + z*k`, multiplication would be something like

```
quaternion operator*(quaternion a, quaternion b) {
    return {
        a.w * b.w - a.x * b.x - a.y * b.y - a.z * b.z,  // 1
        a.w * b.x + a.x * b.w + a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y,  // i
        a.w * b.y - a.x * b.z + a.y * b.w + a.z * b.x,  // j
        a.w * b.z + a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x + a.z * b.w   // k
    };
}
```

(NOTE: that's untested, and probably riddled with typos).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Ordered_list_form).

I would make something like:

```
class Quaternion{
double w,x,y,z;

public:
 Quaternion(double w, double x, double y, double z) : w(w), x(x), y(y), z(z) {};

 operator*(const Quaternion& rhs){
   double _w, _x, _y, _z;
   //compute new values
   _w = w*rhs.w - x*rhs.x - y*rhs.y - z*rhs.z;
   _y = /* after wiki */;
   _x = /* after wiki */;
   _z = /* after wiki */;

   //update values
   w = _w; x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; 
 }
}
```

I.e. make an object with 4 real numbers, write an operator to calculate new coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Expressing the imaginary `xi+yj+zk` as a vector, the multiplication of `Qc{Wc,Vc} = Qa{Wa,Va} * Qb{Wb,Vb}` is as follows:
    `Qc{Wc,Vc} = {WaWb + WaVb + WbVa + VaVb}`.

From `VaVb = -(Va dot Vb) + (Va cross Vb)` [the former is a scaler and the latter is a vector], then grouping scalers and vectors:
    `Qc{Wc,Vc} = {WaWb + -(Va dot Vb), WaVb + WbVa + (Va cross Vb)}`.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting but most of this is so turgid for such a simple question.

The formula for multiplying two quaternions using numpy:

`import numpy as np`

`q1 = np.array([v1, s1])`

`q2 = np.array([v2, s2])`

`q3 = s1*v1 + s2*v2 + np.cross(v1, v2), s1*s2 - np.dot(v1, v2)`